# Warning Control Character '\S' is not valid when concatinating two strings

Tags: matlab

I have two variables such as:

```
path='data\voc11\SegmentationClassExt\%s.png'
name='123'
```

I want to concatenate two strings into one like so:

```
data\voc11\SegmentationClassExt\123.png
```

I used the code below:

```
sprintf(path, name)
```

However I receive the following error:

> Warning: Control Character `'\S'` is not valid. See 'doc `sprintf`' for control characters valid in the format string.

```
ans =

dataoc11
```

I am using MATLAB on Windows. Could you give me any solution for that. I tried to change  `path='data\\voc11\\SegmentationClassExt\\%s.png'` and when I did that, the above code will work. However, the current data is

```
path='data\voc11\SegmentationClassExt\%s.png';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before we start, it's highly advised that you **do not use `path` as a local variable**.  `path` is a global variable that MATLAB uses to resolve function scope, especially if you are going to use any functions from toolboxes.  Overwriting `path` with your own string will actually make MATLAB not function properly.  Use a different variable name.

Now to resolve your problem, you can use either [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) as what @matlabgui has suggested, or if you don't care about OS compatibility and are only working in Windows, you can either manually change the path as you have placed so that you can introduce two back slashes and it will indeed work on Windows OS, or you can perhaps use a string replace function so that all back slashes will be accompanied with an additional back slash.

Either one of these two methods will work:

## Method 1 - Using regular expressions

```
pat = 'data\voc11\SegmentationClassExt\%s.png';
pat_new = regexprep(pat, '\\', '\\\\');
```

The function [`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) performs a string replacement by regular expressions.  We search for all single backslashes and replace them with double backslashes.  Note that the single back slash `\` is a special character in regular expressions so if you explicitly what to look for back slashes, you must place an additional back slash beside it.

## Method 2 - Using [`strrep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html)

```
pat = 'data\voc11\SegmentationClassExt\%s.png';
pat_new = strrep(pat, '\', '\\');
```

`strrep` stands for **Str**ing **Rep**lace.  It works very similar to regular expressions as we have discussed above.  However, what's nice is that you don't have to append an additional back slash when looking for the actual character.

Once you do this, you can use `sprintf` as normal:

```
pat_new = sprintf(pat_new, name);
```

Answer (score 5):

use the matlab function `fullfile`

```
filename = fullfile ( path, [name '.png'] );

or 

filename = fullfile ( path, sprintf ( '%s.png', name ) );
```

Note: you should avoid using `path` as a variable as it is already a Matlab function